# Does it make sense to transpile TypeScript test code when using ts-jest?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I am just wondering if the JavaScript files generated from the TypeScript test files could be of any use later, since type-checking if part of their job (testing), what could we use their JavaScript form for?

Concretely, my `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["./src/__tests__/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./build",
    ...
  }
}
```

I am excluding all test files, they are stored in the `./src/__tests__` folder.

So my question comes down to should I keep the `exclude` setting or not ? What would I need the generated JavaScript test files for ?

Comment: Did you find any answer for that?

Comment: No. And due to work constraints, I switched to `C# and Blazor WebAssembly`, so I am not using TypeScript anymore, for now.